# setting the view visibility to View.GONE in destroyview

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks

I know this is a stupid question but what would happen if I set the View visibility to GONE in onDestroyView would it still retain the context of the activity in case of memory leaks associated with that view.

Comment: `onDestroyView()` is called before the hosting `Activity` is destroyed, in fact `onDestroy()` in an `Activity` is called after `onDetach()` in a `Fragment` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkEjj.png  Not sure of your use case here, but thats the lifecycle...

Answer (score 1):

No, setting the visibility to GONE will only make it won't draw but the object is still there. If you are concerned about memory leaks you should set your view to null to release your view references like this :

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    myView = null;
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```